# Android: How to setup a Typeface Array

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, typeface

In my app, users can download different typeface from server, and thereby can choose different fonts for their textview boxes.

The downloaded fonts are stored inside a folder. Therefore counting the number of typeface, a dynamic number of radiobuttons are inflated in order to let users pick the fonts they like.

For the variable number of typeface, therefore I declared 
`Typeface[] dtf;`

and later on

```
for (int z = 1; z <=num_radio; z++)
{
    dtf[z] = Typeface.createFromFile(tyeface_path[z]); //Line 534
}
```

### Question:

The above code causes NPE as follows:

```
01-01 01:59:24.910: E/AndroidRuntime(9639): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-01 01:59:24.910: E/AndroidRuntime(9639):     at com.abc.abc.Doodlz2.onResume(Doodlz2.java:534)
```

How should I properly declare the Typeface?

```
dtf[z] =new Typeface(this); does not work
```

Comment: dtf or tyeface_path (I presume that must be typeface_path) is null. Have you tried putting breakpoints in your code, to see which of the two is null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using an Object array like that you need to specify the size.

```
Typeface[] dtf = new Typeface[size];
```

Or you can use a List instead.

```
List<Typeface> typefaceList = new ArrayList<Typeface>();
for(int z = 1; z <=num_radio; z++){
    typefaceList.add(Typeface.createFromFile(tyeface_path[z]));
}
```

Also, make sure tyeface_path[z] is not null.

Good Luck!